# Android Wear app says it requires permissions that aren't in my manifest

Tags: android, wear-os, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm making a watch face that I'm planning on publishing soon, but I'm having trouble getting the wearable component to install when the mobile side is (kind of important :p). Here's part of the stack trace from the watch I'm testing on when I installed the signed apk with the embedded wearable apk onto my Nexus 5X running Android Marshmallow:

```
10-13 20:43:50.293    2279-8109/? I/PkgMgrInstallUtil﹕ Sending install intent to PackageInstaller Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSTALL_PACKAGE dat=content://com.google.android.clockwork.home.provider/host/com.twintitanium.watchfaces.cardswatchface/wearable/com.twintitanium.watchfaces.cardswatchface/apk typ=vnd.android.cursor.item/wearable_apk cmp=com.android.packageinstaller/.wear.WearPackageInstallerService (has extras) } forcom.twintitanium.watchfaces.cardswatchface
10-13 20:43:51.168    7981-8110/? W/WearPkgInstallerService﹕ Wearable com.twintitanium.watchfaces.cardswatchface has a permission "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" that is not granted in the host application.
10-13 20:43:51.168    7981-8110/? W/WearPkgInstallerService﹕ Wearable com.twintitanium.watchfaces.cardswatchface has a permission "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" that is not granted in the host application.
10-13 20:43:51.168    7981-8110/? W/WearPkgInstallerService﹕ Wearable com.twintitanium.watchfaces.cardswatchface has a permission "android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" that is not granted in the host application.
```

Indeed, if I go to the installed app on my phone (Cards Watch Face) under settings, I see that 2 permissions, Contacts and Storage, are disabled.

Seems pretty self-explanatory, except that I don't have any of these permissions in my wearable manifest - I only have "com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" and "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK," since they are required for watch faces. And if I try to add these permissions to my mobile and wearable manifests, it still gives the same errors.

This is a new issue, because I had a beta version on the play store that worked, but then I updated to API 23. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your build.gradle files: if you have a dependency on `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'`, it apparently implicitly adds permissions (in this case, Contacts and Storage) since Google Play Services 7.5. Changing that dependency to the specific component `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.1.0'` will get rid of these permissions (and make your apk smaller since it won't include libraries it doesn't use).